# how to detect if incomming miss calls are read

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, phone-call

I am currently detecting missed calls using:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                CallLog.Calls._ID};

        String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE+"="+CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE+" AND NEW = 1";                 

Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,projection,where, null, null);      c.moveToFirst();            
Log.d("CALL", ""+c.getCount());         
if(c.getCount() > 0) 
// code that displays in a textview the number of missed calls;
```

Using a flag I am displaying missed calls to the client.

Is there a **way I can reset the textview value to 0 if the missed calls are read**?

**Is there a broadcast receiver or something that announce me when missed calls are read?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get information on missed calls. You can use following.

```
 String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
 String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";         
 Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
```

In this cursor you will get all details of Missed calls. Then you have to make another call to check if call is read or not. I think using `TimerTask` or using `AlaramManager` you can fill cursor once again. Or if you are displaying in your activity then try to fill it once again when that activity is started.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your relay. So the only way is to re- call the method that detects the missed and unread calls? Isn't there any other way? Can you give me a best example (code) please?

Comment: If you only want to show in activity then I think you must have to fill cursor in onResume() so if you leave application by pressing home button and when returns if code is in onResume() then it will refresh cursor.

Comment: I did change the onResume() method, but what f i m not leaving the app and someone calls and I have a new missed call and my activity is still on the screen.

Comment: Can you help/ There is no change if the activity screen is still opened when i have a missed call